# How to access std class index in php

Tags: php, json

I have an array from Google geo api, this results come in json, so I use json_decode().

```
stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [address_components] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => 78213
                                    [short_name] => 78213
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => postal_code
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => San Antonio
                                    [short_name] => San Antonio
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => locality
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [long_name] => Bexar
                                    [short_name] => Bexar
                                    [types] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => administrative_area_level_2
                                            [1] => political
                                        )

                                )
```

But when ever be  I try to access `$result->0->address_components` I am getting this error

> Parse error: parse error, expecting 'T_STRING' or 'T_VARIABLE' or "{" or "$" in C:\wamp\www\test.php.

How to access 0 index value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `results` is an array. You would access it like:

```
$thevar->results[0]->address_components
```

Using the atcual mapping to `StdClass` with json can be annoying to handle. If you force the entire structure to associative arrays its much easier:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo $dats['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'];
```

Comment: I also try this one but showing me an error of Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: I also used your second solution but showing error Undefined index result

Comment: @SaketB In your post you said you tried `$result->0`. If the code you posted is dumped by `print_r($result)`, you need to use `$result->results[0]`, not `$result[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo $array->results[0]->address_components;
```

and use

```
 json_decode($array,true); // it will convert it to array
```

Answer (score 0):

[result] is an array. and not object

you should use
$geocode is your google returned data.

```
$output = json_decode($geocode);
$output->result[0]->address_components
```

and for fist long_name you should use.

```
$output->result[0]->address_components[0]->long_name
```